# How do I create and plot multiple histograms on the same plot with only 4 sets of raw data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 4 sets of raw data values,

- Data value before change @25 degrees
  ex:[1, 2, 3,..., 10]
- Data value before change @79 degrees
  ex:[0.5, 1, 1.5,..., 5]
- Data value after change @25 degrees
  ex:[5, 6, 7,..., 15]
- Data value after change @79 degrees
  ex:[2.5, 3, 3.5,..., 7.5]

And I would like to create a histogram using these data sets, where each data set is its own series. Each data set would be stored in its own array, so it will not need any separation.

Comment: so you want one histogram which contains data from 4 data sets?

Comment: Yes but I would like each data set to be differentiable i.e. different colors.

Comment: See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dAZ4.png), as per duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create sample data
d1 = np.random.normal(10, 5, 100)
d2 = np.random.normal(4, 1, 100)
d3 = np.random.normal(20, 4, 100)
d4 = np.random.normal(2, 1, 100)

f, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.hist(d1, label='d1')
ax.hist(d2, label='d2')
ax.hist(d3, label='d3')
ax.hist(d4, label='d4')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]